# Return link to redirect url

Tags: google-apps-script, redirect, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, urlfetch

I'm trying to get the url of the final destination of a specific website, but all the templates I've found to use as a function in my spreadsheet, only return the initial link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50733029

```
function getRedirect(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false});
  var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location']; // undefined if no redirect, so...
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (redirectUrl) {                                   // ...if redirected...
    var nextRedirectUrl = getRedirect(redirectUrl);    // ...it calls itself recursively...
    Logger.log(url + " is redirecting to " + redirectUrl + ". (" + responseCode + ")");
    return nextRedirectUrl;
  }
  else {                                               // ...until it's not
    Logger.log(url + " is canonical. (" + responseCode + ")");
    return url;
  }
}
```

This is the model where I put:
`=getRedirect("https://c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1067471289?-833:12")`

In the spreadsheet it returns:
`https://c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1067471289?-833:12`

I would like to collect the link to after redirect:
`https://sports.ndtv.com/football/europa-league-bruno-fernandes-double-helps-manchester-united-thrash-real-sociedad-gareth-bale-stars-for-tottenham-2373767`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw the HTML of the URL `https://c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1067471289?-833:12`, I thought that in this case, the value of `https://sports.ndtv.com/football/europa-league-bruno-fernandes-double-helps-manchester-united-thrash-real-sociedad-gareth-bale-stars-for-tottenham-2373767` might be able to be directly retrieved using `IMPORTXML` and a xpath. The sample formula is as follows.

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//a/@href")
```

- In this case, please put the URL of `https://c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1067471289?-833:12` to the cell "A1".

#### Result:

[image]

#### Using Google Apps Script:

When you want to use Google Apps Script, you can also use the following script. In this case, please put a custom formula of `=SAMPLE("https://c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1067471289?-833:12")` to a cell.

```
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const v = res.match(/url: '([\s\S\w]+?)'/);
  return v && v.length == 2 ? v[1].trim() : "Value cannot be retrieved.";
}
```

#### Note:

- In this sample formula and xpath is for the URL of `https://c.newsnow.co.uk/A/1067471289?-833:12`. So when you use this for other URLs, it might not be able to be used. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)