# How do I get urlfetchapp.fetch() to continue through a redirect?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

When I input the this [link](https://www.walmart.com/grocery/v3/api/products/44391159?itemFields=all&storeId=4456&nutritionPrescriptive=true) into my importJSON function (code below) it goes to to https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.walmart.com/grocery/v3/api/products/44391159?itemFields=all&storeId=4456&nutritionPrescriptive=true before redirecting to the actual link. This is (I believe) causing me to get this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (line 222).
```

Occasionally, I get success so I think that since google first does this before redirecting to the actual link is causing the problem, how do I get around this? Here is the code I'm working with:

```js
function ImportJSON(url, query, parseOptions) {
  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, null, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}

function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
  
  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

Comment: in case of redirect you can check it in response using `jsondata.redirected` and skip

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098169/what-google-appsscript-method-is-used-to-get-the-url-of-a-redirect

Comment: @MetaMan how would I apply this in my situtation? Sorry, I'm still pretty new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this used something like this in a recent question:

```
let url ='something'
do{
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false});
  let redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location'];
  if(redirectUrl) url = redirectUrl;
  //You can potentially do something in here between redirects if you wish
}while(url)
```