# Google Apps Script: UrlFetchApp delivers code 302

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, http-status-code-302

I need your help with the issue which is bugging me since a couple hours. I part of my code just doesn't want to run for me:

```
  var options = {'muteHttpExceptions': true, 'AllowAutoRedirect': true};
  var url = "https://www.auftrag.at//tenders.aspx"
  var firstResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  Logger.log(firstResponse.getContentText());
  if(firstResponse.getResponseCode() == 200){....
```

This always delivers the following response (Code 302):

```
<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
    <h2>Object moved to <a href="/tenders.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1">here</a>.</h2>
    </body></html>
```

Can you please help me in fixing this? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Google AppsScript method is used to get the URL of a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098169/what-google-appsscript-method-is-used-to-get-the-url-of-a-redirect)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is still a problem

After the first iteration, the redirectURL is: "/tenders.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1", which makes the next iteration fail since it's not a valid URL. 
If I adapt the code with 
var nextRedirectUrl = getRedirect("https://www.auftrag.at/"+ redirectUrl);
I get stuck in an endless loop

Comment: then it looks like you deal with wrongly configured web server

Comment: I think the issue is more related to the missing Cookie Support

Comment: still looks like web server issue, anyway Apps Script supports sending cookies same as regular headers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869932/cookie-handling-in-google-apps-script-how-to-send-cookies-in-header